# google infoBox position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to position my infoBox based on the latLng of the markers, I tried position (latLng) but no avail and I don't want to hardcode the pixelOffset as that will not correspond to the marker position, I also tried pixelOffset(latLng), getPosition and setPosition methods.

None of the above seems to be doing it right :/

```
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            var Lat = data[i].Item.Coordinate.Lat;
            var Lon = data[i].Item.Coordinate.Lon;
            var LatLon = new gm.LatLng(jobLat, +jobLon);

            var marker = new gm.Marker({
                position: LatLon,
                map: map,
                visible: true
            });

            var infobox = new InfoBox ({
                position: marker.position or LatLon
            });

            marker.newContent = document.getElementById("infobox_"+data[i].Item.Id);

            gm.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker) {
                return function (pin, suppressInfoWindow) {
                    if (!suppressInfoWindow) {
                            infobox.setContent(marker.newContent);
                            infobox.open(map, marker);
                    }
            }
}
resultMarkers.push(marker);
```

This seems to be working okay

```
var infoboxWidth = -650/2;
        if(getWidth === 'xs'){
            infoboxWidth = -320/2;
        }

        var infobox = new InfoBox({
            pixelOffset: new gm.Size(infoboxWidth, -65),
            alignBottom: true
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop over your `data` array, creating markers.
Each time, you re-initialise the `infobox` variable to use the current marker's position.
At the end of the loop, you have 1 variable called `infobox` with the position of the last marker.

When you then click on any of your markers, it'll open that infobox at that position.  Not the position that the n-th iteration of your re-created infobox variable had at the moment you create the marker.

All you need to do is set the position of the infobox in your event listener.

```
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    var Lat = data[i].Item.Coordinate.Lat;
    var Lon = data[i].Item.Coordinate.Lon;
    var LatLon = new gm.LatLng(jobLat, +jobLon);

    var marker = new gm.Marker({
        position: LatLon,
        map: map,
        visible: true
    });

    var infobox = new InfoBox();

    marker.newContent = document.getElementById("infobox_"+data[i].Item.Id);

    gm.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker) {
        return function (pin, suppressInfoWindow) {
            if (!suppressInfoWindow) {
                    infobox.setContent(marker.newContent);
                    infobox.setPosition(marker.getPosition());
                    infobox.open(map, marker);
            }
    }
}
resultMarkers.push(marker);
```

Comment: Yeah i tried that but its always putting the infoBox in the wrong place not where the marker is.

Comment: tried using pixelOffset but that's only work based on the width of the infoBox and basically dividing the width by 2 to get the offSet position. But I don't thin that's idea when it comes to mobile. Say infoBox is 600px width on lg screen and 320px width on mobile.

Comment: Can you add screenshots that demonstrate the problem?